# Setting flags for chromium-browser to optimize video stream

Tags: video, chromium

I'm currently running on Raspbian 11 trying to set flags for chromium-browser to enable hardware acceleration. I've tried editing /etc/chromium.d/00-rpi-vars according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1385776/how-should-i-enable-hardware-graphics-acceleration-in-chromium-web-browser-runni?newreg=c03c6d1c65284e9ebd7ea4b02b26edd5) solution, yet it doesn't seem to work. When I open chrome://gpu I get

> - Canvas: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
> - Canvas out-of-process rasterization: Disabled
> - Direct Rendering Display Compositor: Disabled
> - Compositing: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
> - Multiple Raster Threads: Disabled
> - Out-of-process Rasterization: Disabled
> - OpenGL: Disabled
> - Rasterization: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
> - Raw Draw: Disabled
> - Skia Renderer: Enabled
> - Video Decode: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
> - Video Encode: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
> - Vulkan: Disabled
> - WebGL: Disabled
> - WebGL2: Disabled

along with 3 problems detected

> - Accelerated video encode has been disabled, either via blocklist, about:flags or the command line. *Disabled Features: video_encode*
> - Gpu composting has been disabled, either via blocklist, about:flags or the command line. The browser will fall back to software composting and hardware acceleration will be unavailable. *Disabled Features: gpu_composting*
> - GPU process was unable to boot: GPU process crashed too many times with SwiftShader. *Disabled Features: all*

How to fix these problems and enable hardware acceleration via terminal?

Comment: Hi did you find a solution? Thanks